# Laravel meilisearch encrypted data

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I'm trying to search in my encrypted model with mailisearch in Laravel.
I tried with database and mailisearch so far, but no success. I'm using default laravel encryption. Here is how I defined `toSearchableArray`:

```
public function toSearchableArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => Crypt::decryptString($this->description)
        ];
    }
```

So in that case, when I try to import or search the data, it will return that Payload is invalid. Title field is working, cause it's not encrypted.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need to decrypt it :D
It worked like 'description' => $this->description